# jasperserver 6.3.0 report url generation

Tags: jsf, report, jasperserver

I'm developing a web application using java, primefaces and bootsfaces. I want to integrate jasperserver for report generation, so I installed Jasperserver 6.3.0 on Tomcat 8.5. I created report and report unit on repository, added a button on my xhtml page binded to a method which returns report url:

```
http://localhost:9000/jasperserver/flow.html?_flowId=viewReportFlow&ParentFolderUri=/CUSTOMER_FOLDER&reportUnit=/CUSTOMER_FOLDER/REPORT_UNIT_NAME&j_username=jasperadmin&j_password=jasperadmin&docHeaderId=91&output=pdf
```

This url opens jasperserver web interface but it shows a dialog with report parameter filled.

Where is the problem?

Comment: How is this JSF related? I see just a link, nothing more... Please read [ask] and improve your question

Comment: Hi @Kukeltje, call report generation from url is indipendent from JSF ... read complete question! ;) 

However, I found the problem: on JasperServer web interface I have to unflag "Always prompt" from parameter config!

Comment: No I did read it correctly... that is why asked how it was JSF related... And I was right as you confirm. So it is independent of JSF then please remove the jsf tag

Answer (score 1):

It's always a bit confusing if questions are answered in the comments section, so let me repeat the answer given by @xc93hil themselves:

The intermediate dialog was shown because the parameter "always prompt" was activated. Unflagging it in the JasperServer web interface solved the problem.